# ¿Como transformar yarn.lock en package-lock.json?

Tags: nodejs, npm, yarn

Tengo un proyecto que he estado trabajando en `yarn` y ahora por cuestiones de compactibilidad quiero incluir la opcion para que tambien funcione con `npm`.

¿Saben como puedo transformar el archivo `yarn.lock` en un `package-lock.json`?

*La verdad no estoy buscando trucos o convenciones que puedo hacer como borrar la carpeta `node_modules` y generar el nuevo constructo con `npm`. Quiero saber si hay una manera soportada por estos gestores de paquetes, como un comando o algo sin utilizar librerias de terceros.*